# how can i verify if username already exists in react native and firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

this is part of my code... i want to check if a username already exists on the database in firebase

````
        try {
            await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
            const uid = Firebase.getCurrentUser().uid;

            let profilePhotoUrl = "default";



            await db.collection("users").doc(uid).set({
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                profilePhotoUrl
            })
            code............
  
    },```
````

Comment: You going to be a little stuck on this. If your database does not allow reading of data unless a user is authenticated, there isn't a way to query for the duplicate user name. So, the only option there is to create a publicly readable node that contains only user names so before attempting to create a user with a certain username, you can check for it. Otherwise you could allow the user to create their account and *then* select a username. That way that would at least be authenticated so you can keep the users node from being publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase will handle the duplication of entries for you.

```
await firebase.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword('jane.doe@example.com', 'SuperSecretPassword!')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User account created & signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
      console.log('That email address is already in use!');
    }

    if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      console.log('That email address is invalid!');
    }

    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: and if i want to verify the username? how can i do that?

Comment: I did not understand your question @CookieDeveloper please elaborate.

Comment: If you want to check username then you need to query the firestore database to check if a user with that username exists as it seems like you are writing it to "users" collection.

Comment: The OP is asking about duplicate data in Firebase (they call it 'username') and that is unrelated to duplicate user authentication which is what this answer addresses.

Comment: yes, if someone knows how can i do that, please tell me, thanks.